# Understanding Linear Recurrence Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, roots

I have been trying to understand this theorem but I could not get past a point. The proof has been taken from Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics.

> **THEOREM 1:** Let c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> be real numbers.
>   Suppose that r<sup>2</sup> − c<sub>1</sub>r − c<sub>2</sub> = 0 has
>   two distinct roots r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub>. Then the sequence
>   {a<sub>n</sub>} is a solution of the recurrence relation a<sub>n</sub>
>   = α<sub>1</sub> a<sub>n−1</sub> + α<sub>2</sub> a<sub>n−2</sub> if and only if a<sub>n</sub> =α<sub>1</sub> r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>
>   +α<sub>2</sub> r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> for n=0,1,2,...,where α<sub>1</sub> and α<sub>2</sub> are constants.
>
> **PROOF :** We must do two things to prove the theorem. First, it must be shown that if r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> are the roots of the
>   characteristic equation, and α<sub>1</sub> and α<sub>2</sub> are
>   constants, then the sequence {a<sub>n</sub>} with a<sub>n</sub> =
>   α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> is a solution of the recurrence
>   relation.  Second, it must be shown that if the sequence
>   {a<sub>n</sub>} is a solution, then a<sub>n</sub> =
>   α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> for some constants
>   α<sub>1</sub> and α<sub>2</sub>.
>
> Now we will show that if a<sub>n</sub> =
>   α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup>, then the sequence
>   {a<sub>n</sub>} is a solution of the recurrence relation.Because
>   r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> are roots of r<sup>2</sup> −
>   c<sub>1</sub>r − c<sub>2</sub> = 0, it follows that
>   r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> = c<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> +c<sub>2</sub>,
>   r<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> =c<sub>1</sub>r<sub>2</sub> +c<sub>2</sub>.

Now until this part what I have understood(if I am right) that they have just taken a quadratic equation and split it into its roots.

Now the following algebraic part did not make any sense to me. I want to understand this part:

> c<sub>1</sub>a<sub>n−1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>a<sub>n−2</sub> =
>   c<sub>1</sub>(α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n−1</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n−1</sup>) +
>   c<sub>2</sub>(α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n−2</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n−2</sup>)
>
> = α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n−2</sup>(c<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>) + α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n−2</sup>(c<sub>1</sub>r<sub>2</sub> +
>   c<sub>2</sub>)
>
> = α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n−2</sup>r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n−2</sup>r<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>
>
> = α<sub>1</sub> r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + α<sub>2</sub> r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup>
>
> = a<sub>n</sub>.
>
> This shows that the sequence {a<sub>n</sub>} with a<sub>n</sub> =
>   α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> +
>   α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> is a solution of the recurrence
>   relation.

Now I have omitted rest of the proof because I could no get past this point. If someone requires it I can edit it. or If someone can explain further part in simple english I would be very grateful for that. But for now I just want to understand the above part.

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra?  There is an easy-to-understand explanation if you are.

Comment: yes I am familiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions to linear recurrence relations started making a lot more sense to me once I found a source that tied it to linear algebra.  I won't spell out all of the details, but "the interested reader" can verify most of it.

---

Consider $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$, the linear space of real sequences with termwise addition and termwise scalar multiplication.  The key idea is that the set of all real sequences that satisfy a linear recurrence relation is a subspace of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$.  You can check for yourself that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy $f_n=\alpha f_{n-1}+\beta f_{n-2}$ then so do $(c:n\mapsto a_n+b_n)$ and $(d:n\mapsto ka_n)$.

$$c_n=a_n+b_n=(\alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2})+(\alpha b_{n-1}+\beta b_{n-2})\\=\alpha (a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})+\beta(a_{n-2}+b_{n-2})=(\alpha c_{n-1}+\beta c_{n-2})$$

$$d_n=ka_n=k(\alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2})=\alpha ka_{n-1}+\beta ka_{n-2}=(\alpha d_{n-1}+\beta d_{n-2})$$

So, since being a solution to a linear recurrence relation is preserved by addition and scalar multiplication, the set of all solutions is a subspace of all real sequences.  Since an $n$'th degree linear recurrence relation is defined by assigning the first $n$ terms of the sequence, it stands to reason that the dimension of the subspace is $n$.  Now we are just left with finding a basis for the subspace.

---

So assume that $(n\mapsto r^n)$ for some real non-zero $r$ satisfies the recurrence relation.  Then $$r^n=\alpha r^{n-1}+\beta r^{n-2}\\r^2=\alpha r+\beta\\ r^2-\alpha r-\beta=0\\$$

Long story short, for a two-term linear recurrence relation whose characteristic polynomial has distinct roots, a basis for the subspace of solutions $(n\mapsto r^n_1)$ and $(n\mapsto r^n_2)$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  Therefore, the set of all solutions is the linear combinations of those two basis solutions.

Comment: This is a little tough for me to understand. Could you simplify it a bit more? What I have gathered is that is some value satisfies the linear recurrence so does addition of values which satisfy it and any multiple of value which satisfy the equation

Comment: @sachal I've had some things to get done today, but I added in some extra work that shows a little more of the work.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: No i am still finding it hard to understand. I think once I understand what is trying to convey then after that i would be able to understand the math of this proof. I am still trying to figure what it is really we are trying to achieve